# Can ArcGIS Explorer open *.mxd files?

Tags: mxd, arcgis-explorer

This is perhaps a silly question but can ArcGIS Explorer open a .mxd file?

I can't seem to find a definite answer online and I can't download it until I know the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mxd map document cannot be opened in ArcGIS Explorer.

You can add layer packages and data such as some but not all ArcGIS online basemaps, OGIS web mapping service (WMS) data, a KML/KMZ files, geodatabases, shapefiles, GPX, and  rasters JPEG 2000, GeoTIFF, MrSID rasters. As for layer packages; these have to be first created and uploaded into ArcGIS online via ArcMap before they can be opened in ArcGIS Explorer. (1200 or more recent)

Sources:

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/09/15/arcgis-explorer-groups-on-arcgis-online/

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/help/index.html#//015600000040000000

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/key-features.html

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisdesktop/10.0/sharing

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you cannot open .mxd files in ArcGIS Explorer

You can open these item types in ArcGIS Explorer Desktop:

- ArcGIS Explorer document (.nmf)
- ArcGIS Explorer application configuration (.ncfg)
- ArcGIS layer (.lyr)
- ArcGIS layer package (.lpk)
- ArcGIS Explorer layer (.nmc)
- ArcGIS Explorer add-in (.eaz)
- ArcGIS Server service
- Web map

Please see this page: 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisonline/help/index.html#//010q0000000v000000